# assert.async() never fails

Tags: sapui5, qunit

I am new to OpenUI5/QUnit testing. Sorry for the newbie question.

I have added a very basic async QUnit test into my OpenUI5 project:

```
QUnit.test( "Test async", function( assert ) {
    var done = assert.async();
    setTimeout(function() {
        assert.ok(true);
        done();
    });
});
```

This test passes without errors as expected.
Then I have commented out everything except for

```
var done = assert.async();
```

The test runs indefinitely without failing. I would expect that it fails after some timeout.

Pressing the "Abort" button just changes the label to "Aborting" but does not fail the test.

I have search the [QUnit documentation](https://api.qunitjs.com/assert/timeout), that suggest adding

```
assert.timeout( 1000 ); // Timeout of 1 second
```

that should be an equivalent to global setting

```
QUnit.config.testTimeout( 1000 );
```

But using either crash my test with

```
assert.timeout is not a function
```

or

```
QUnit.config.testTimeout is not a function
```

I have tried running the test in Chrome, Firefox and IE11 with the same results.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer myself. The correct syntax is:

```
QUnit.config.testTimeout = 1000;
```

It is then valid for all the subsequent tests. Alternatively I can write

```
assert.timeout(1000);
```

at the beginning of the test method - must be before `assert.async()`